# Count iterations of an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, count, each

I have a variable returning an array from the DB. Inside that array I need to count the instances of a specific object iteration.

I tried using jQuery.each and logging the output to check but was just getting individual results in the console. I was not getting the desired count. In the sample below I would expect to see:
size 2 - count 1
size 4 - count 2

**Sample Output**

```
   0: {Email: "example@mai.com", Name: "Bob Smith", ​Number: "555-555-1234", Size: "2"}
    
    1: { Email: "example2@mai.com",  Name: "Jenny Girl", ​Number: "222-333-1234",  Size: "4"}
    
    2: {  Email: "example3@mai.com",   Name: "Johnny on the spot",  ​Number: "111-777-1234",  Size: "4"}
```

Using jquery what is the best way to achieve this? Is using something like `.size`?

My code I have attempted:

```
​​function xyz() {
jQuery.ajax({
data: {action: 'my_action'},
type: 'post',
url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function(data) {
jQuery.each(data, function(key,val){
var n = Object.keys(val.Size).size;
console.log(n);
        });
```

​​
​​This gives me an 'undefined' console log readout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the value of `Size` as the property of an Object and count:

```js
// Just for demo - that's your data response:
const data = [{Size: "2"}, {Size: "4"}, {Size: "4"}, {Size: "99"}]; 

const sizes = data.reduce((ob, item) => {
  if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(item.Size)) ob[item.Size] = 0;
  ++ob[item.Size];
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(sizes);
```

Comment: Thanks! Using this do I have to manually define the sizes or can it read it dynamically?

Comment: @user14955679 I don't understand the question... The most important in the above is simply the property is always called `Size` case sensitive. Nothing else. You cannot automagically determine the cumulative count without iterating every item inside the Array.

Comment: In the code `const response = [{Size: "2"}, {Size: "4"}, {Size: "4"}];` You have manually had to type each size. Is it possible to replace that with (data) and let it pull out the sizes and then count them? Hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: If you're interested in the `Size` property, you need to define it - hardcode it (just like in the example above `item.Size`). If `Size` is *not* the property you want to hardcode, than create a function that accepts as argument the property name you want to use instead of "Size" - and instead of  `item.Size` use `item[myPropertyName]`

Comment: Sorry maybe I am still not making sense. I am looking to have this look through the (data) find the instances of size and then their value, then count each.  Where you typed this `const response = [{Size: "2"}, {Size: "4"}, {Size: "4"}];` youve manually entered, {Size: "2"} etc. To do that, I would have to know how many of each exists to count it. I am missing how to dynamically have the code retrieve this form the data without me typing in {Size: "2"} or {Size: "4"} for each instance. Am I making more sense?

Comment: @user14955679 I used a hardcoded response as `data`. Don't get confused - it's just for demo purpose to emulate some data. Edited - you just need to delete the first line of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense. I am not at all familiar with .reduce and am trying to read the manual at the same time I am chatting with you to better understand it. Sorry to be a pain and thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You're welcome! Here's a useful documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score -1):

```js
var data = [
  {Email: "example@mai.com", Name: "Bob Smith", Number: "555-555-1234", Size: "2"},
  {Email: "example2@mai.com", Name: "Jenny Girl", Number: "222-333-1234",  Size: "4"},
  {Email: "example3@mai.com", Name: "Johnny on the spot", Number: "111-777-1234",  Size: "4"}
];

const sizes = data
    // collect each "Size" value from the data
    .map(e => e.Size)
    // use an object to count each instance
    .reduce((a, n) => ({...a, [n]: (a[n] || 0) + 1 }), {})

// log each object entry to the console
Object.entries(sizes)
    .forEach(([size, count]) => console.log(`size: ${size} count: ${count}`));
```